# How to fix basename of containers when using docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

It seems that `docker-compose` adds current folder name as a base-name for each created container. So for following directory structure:

```
/myproj/docker-compose.yml
```

and docker-compose.yml content:

```
web: ...
worker: ...
```

docker-compose will create following containers:

```
myproj_web_1
myproj_worker_1
```

I don't mind the suffix (`_X`) however I would like to "fix" myproj to some constant like "always_same" so I could move docker-compose.yml file around and still have containers with same names.

How I can do it?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There are two ways to do this.

Set the environment variable with

```
export COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=foo
```

or by starting your stack with the `-p` switch

```
docker-compose -p foo build
docker-compose -p foo up
```

Comment: I am wondering why it's not possible to set project name in yml file - I guess it would be most convenient...

Comment: Put `COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=foo` in `.env` file and you are good to go.

Comment: Not if you use 2 compose files in the same directory (e.g. one for dev, another for test).

Comment: What if you don't want the underscore but a dash?

Comment: Also what if you want an underscore in the middle of the project name?  My folder is xxx-yyy but with docker compose I am now getting xxxyyy without the dash

Answer (score 2):

you can add this to the .yml file

```
container_name: my-web-container
```

as said [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#container_name)

Comment: Yes but this won't allow me to scale this container. I would like to change just basename (prefix) of all container to fixed name instead of directory name...

Comment: @Chris broken link

Comment: For me, it does not give the name to the composition but to the container. The "-p" option seems to be the best solution for me (but still outside the yaml file which is not optimal).